# Python number comparison for negative numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

For a list of numbers separated by commas, find the largest single digit number and print it. Print "No single digit numbers found" in-case the input doesn't contain any single digit number. Print "Invalid Input" in-case of invalid input.

```
chars=input()
a=([int(x.strip()) for x in chars.split(',')])
b=len(a)
print(a)
max=0
for i in range(b-1):
    for j in range(i,b):
        if a[i]<10 and a[j]<10:

            if a[i]>a[j]:
                #print(a[i])
                max=a[i]
            else:
                max=a[j]

if (max!=0):
    print(max)
else:
    print('No single digit numbers found')
```

if i give the above code the program works fine for positive numbers but if i work with negative numbers i get wrong output

```
OUTPUT positive number works fine
1,2,3
[1, 2, 3]
3
```

Output for negative number(wrong output)

```
  -9,+3,0,20,-10,-11,11
    [-9, 3, 0, 20, -10, -11, 11]
    -11
```

Comment: -11<10 as per your condition. `if a[i]<10 and a[j]<10:`

Comment: `if a[i]<10 and a[j]<10:` why is that condition necessary?

Comment: it should be a single digit positive number and negative number has no condition

Comment: try, a=([int(x.strip()) for x in chars.split(',') if int(x.strip())>=0]) which will ignore negative numbers at initial stage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to concentrate on numbers in the range `-10 < i < 10`
I propose a different solution, somewhat simpler than yours:

```
$ cat /tmp/tmp.py
from __future__ import print_function
import random

def max_single_digit(N):
    cur_max = -10
    for i in N:
        if (i > cur_max) and (-10 < i < 10):
            cur_max = i
    if cur_max > -10:
        return cur_max
    else:
        return "No single digit numbers found"


_range = 20

negatives = tuple([random.randint(-100,0) for x in range(_range)])
positives = tuple([random.randint(0,100) for x in range(_range)])
numbers   = tuple([random.randint(-100,100) for x in range(_range)])

for nums in (negatives, positives, numbers):
    print("For", nums, "the result is:", max_single_digit(nums),"\n")
```

Which gives:

```
$ python /tmp/tmp.py
For (0, -31, -87, -80, -47, -21, -21, -14, -37, -43, -71, -61, -47, -4, -36, -72, -78, -83, -14, -70) the result is: 0

For (17, 83, 80, 50, 35, 43, 9, 75, 23, 38, 45, 55, 46, 99, 80, 93, 36, 97, 88, 30) the result is: 9

For (-1, 30, -20, -68, 13, -66, -71, 92, 77, 85, -100, 8, 32, 92, -6, 97, 40, 21, 13, -48) the result is: 8


$ python /tmp/tmp.py
For (-94, -94, -28, -37, -50, -5, -29, -51, -6, -24, -18, -46, -32, -20, -89, -49, -55, -39, -50, -30) the result is: -5

For (91, 4, 16, 68, 6, 100, 61, 92, 81, 65, 63, 87, 67, 67, 97, 89, 98, 53, 40, 89) the result is: 6

For (11, 49, 63, -17, 71, 50, 28, 5, 31, -100, -35, -5, -8, 77, -87, 77, 3, 8, -39, -97) the result is: 8

$ python /tmp/tmp.py
For (-55, -48, -52, -75, -1, -89, -53, -66, -48, -17, -9, -96, -16, -40, -52, 0, -90, -97, -40, -85) the result is: 0

For (52, 19, 82, 45, 54, 47, 94, 54, 46, 8, 66, 22, 100, 25, 0, 81, 79, 39, 5, 20) the result is: 8

For (-43, -32, 92, -59, -91, 63, -95, 100, -85, -21, 35, -88, -38, 43, -25, 85, 76, 67, -82, 87) the result is: No single digit numbers found
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just use the max() function:

```
max( x, y, z, .... )
```

More here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_max.htm

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import re

input = "1,2,3,44,5,6,-7,-10"
nums = [int(el) for el in input.split(",") if re.match("^-?\d$", el) is not None]
if len(nums) == 0:
    print("No single digit numbers found")
print(max(nums))
```